# Apollo GraphQL Error expected " ] " found " : "

Tags: javascript, react-apollo, graphql-js

Hey I'm getting an error when I run my app. it is `GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected "]", found ":".`
At the bottom of the stack trace it has `path: undefined, [0]   locations: [ { line: 12, column: 17 } ],`

Here's my typeDefs.js

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server-express");

const typeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    _id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
  }

  type Metric {
    _id: ID
    name: String
    labels: [key: String!, value: String!]
    values: [value: Number!, timestamp: Date!]
  }

  type Auth {
    token: ID
    user: User
  }

  type Query {
    user: User
    userById(userId: ID): User
    metric(metricId: ID): Metric
    metrics: [Metric]!
  }

  type Mutation {
    addUser(
      firstName: String!
      lastName: String!
      email: String!
      password: String!
    ): Auth
    updateUser(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String): User
    login(email: String!, password: String!): Auth
    addMetric(
      name: String!
      labels: [key: String!, value: String!]
      values: [value: Number!, timestamp: Date!]
      ): Metric
  }
`;

module.exports = typeDefs;
```

Here's my Model for metrics as i'm assuming it has something to do with how im setting up the arrays in graphql, maybe this will help!

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const metricsSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  labels: [
    {
      key: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      value: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  values: [
    {
      value: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
});

const Metrics = mongoose.model("Metrics", metricsSchema);
module.exports = Metrics;
```

Thanks..

I tried changing how the arrays are wrote in the typeDefs and could not get past this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding new type for `label` and `value`.

```
type Label {
  key: String!
  value: String!
}

type Value {
  value: Number!
  timeStamp: Date!
}

type Metric {
  _id: ID
  name: String
  labels: [Label!]
  values: [Value!]
}

// Change type of addMetric params in your mutations

type Mutation {
  addMetric(
    name: String!
    labels: [Label!]
    values: [Value!]
    ): Metric
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use curly braces for object types:

```
// in typeDefs.js
type Metric {
  _id: ID
  name: String
  labels: [{key: String!, value: String!}]
  values: [{value: Number!, timestamp: Date!}]
}
```